# Setting up an Xcode framework that uses Realm, on multiple platforms

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, watchkit, realm

Any help on how to set up Xcode & Realm for the following configuration would be greatly appreciated. I really don't know where to begin.

```
Amazing.app
--AmazingTodayExtension.appex
--AmazingWatchKitApp.app/.appex
--DataKit.framework
----Realm.framework
----RealmSwift.framework
```

The purpose of `DataKit` is to have a common model shared between the host iOS App, the Today Extension and the watchOS Extension. My head says that I should be linking `Realm` and `RealmSwift` to the `DataKit` framework and then linking `DataKit` to the host app and the two app extensions.

This is where I get stuck. All the guides I have read talk about choosing either `ios/swift2.1/Realm.framework` or `watchOS/swift2.1/Realm.framework` when adding them to a project. This would need both?!

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create two targets for iOS and watchOS architectures for DataKit.　For example, `DataKit-iOS` and `DataKit-watchOS` (As Realm project does, using `xcconfig`s, you can also correspond to multiple architectures in a single target. But at first it is easier to make the two targets.)

Then Link `DataKit-iOS` to `Realm` and `RealmSwfit` for iOS, link `DataKit-watchOS` to for watchOS frameworks.

You can share all model code between `DataKit-iOS` and `DataKit-watchOS` like `Realm` does. And you can make the frameworks same name by the Both "PRODUCT_NAME" as "DataKit" in build settings.

So the following structure is I suggested.

```
├── Amazing.xcodeproj
├── AmazingTodayExtension
├── AmazingWatchKitApp
├── AmazingWatchKitApp\ Extension
├── DataKit
└── Frameworks
    ├── iOS
    │   ├── DataKit.framework
    │   ├── Realm.framework
    │   └── RealmSwift.framework
    └── watchOS
        ├── DataKit.framework
        ├── Realm.framework
        └── RealmSwift.framework
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks.
I was getting stuck on importing the watchOS versions of Realm/RealmSwift into my project that already contained the iOS versions, so if anyone stumbles across this, it seems you must remove the iOS versions and then add both at the same time.